# Using Toad 9.5 for Oracle how to sort numeric field that has dash

Tags: oracle, t-sql, sorting, toad

So I'm trying to sort a field that has data that looks like this:

```
"Order Number"
1-123456
1-223456
1-33356

order by "Order Number" desc
```

The intent is to sort the order numbers from most recent to oldest. Every order number will start with 1-, never a 2- or 3- etc....  But the issue is that in the above example it shows 1-33356 as the most recent.  But if you can picture the order numbers with the 1- removed and are talking value, 33,356 is < 123,456.  How can I get this to sort based on the total value of the digits after 1-????

Thanks for help in advance.  I love this site!

Comment: Use a string value to represent chronology is poor design. What you'd have to do is zero-pad the numbers after the hyphen to as many positions are in the largest "number" and then reassemble the chunks, if 2-000000001 would represent a value that came later than 1-938394383

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you want numerical order of the contents of a string (that will be ordered lexicographycally).

you should extract the number part of the string and convert it to number to order with.
something like this

```
select * from yourtable
order by to_number(substring(ordernumber, 3));
```